# Bash/Shell Combine options using find

Tags: macos, bash, shell, find

Using the `find` command is there a way to combine options:

i.e.

```
find . -type fd -name "somefile"
```

Although `-type` ignores the second option; I'm looking to find only files or directories.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `-o` for **OR condition** in find:

```
find . \( -type d -o -type f \) -name "somefile"
```

Comment: Are the `()` brackets required?

Comment: I believe yes they are needed since rest of the qualifiers like `-name`, `-maxdepth` will be ANDed.

Comment: My tests showed that they are not necessary because `and` is default and arguments concatened with `-o` will get "automatically"  parenthesized.. (But I'm not 100% sure)

Comment: Actually even in this example it is very much required. Otherwise your find command will list **all the files** and **directories with name somefile**. Test it by reversing the `-type` as in `find . -type d -o -type f -name "somefile"` and you will see different output.

Comment: @anubhava, i tried this with and without the parenthesis and it does seem to require them — thank you. one more question, why does there have to be two `-type` options anyway? i would have thought there would be a way to combine them as `-type fd` or `-type { d, f }` or something... just curious.

Comment: Actually as far as I know there is now way to combine 2 `-type` qualifiers into one. `Multiple -name` can usually be combined into one using `-regex` though.

Comment: @anubhava, Interesting, and a bit surprising — thanks again, much appreciated :)